# O(log n) solution to 1a + 2a^2 + 3a^3 + ... + na^n

Tags: algorithm, math

The task is to find the sum of the equation given `n` and `a`. So for the equation `1a + 2a^2 + 3a^3 + ... + na^n`, we can find the n-th element in the sequence with the following formula (from observation):

`n-th element = a^n * (n-(n-2)/n-(n-1)) * (n-(n-3)/n-(n-2)) * ... * (n/(n-1))`

I think that it's impossible to simplify the sum of n elements by modifying the above formula to a sum formula. Even if it is possible, I assume that it will involve the use of exponent `n`, which will introduce a n-time loop; thus causing the solution to not be O(log n). The best solution I can get is simply find the ratio of each element, which is `a(n+1)/n` and apply that to the `n-1` element to find the `n-th` element.

I think that I may be missing something. Could someone provide me with solution(s)?

Comment: `https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+j*a%5Ej,+j%3D1+to+n`. And you can do exponentiation in `O(log n)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can solve this problem, and lots of problems like it, with matrix exponentiation.

Let's start with this sequence:

```
A[n] = a + a^2 + a^3 ... + a^n
```

That sequence can be generated with a simple formula:

```
A[i] = a*(A[i-1] + 1)
```

Now if we consider your sequence:

```
B[n] = a + 2a^2 + 3a^3 ... + na^n
```

We can generate that with a formula that makes use of the previous one:

```
B[i] = (B[i-1] + A[i-1] + 1) * a
```

If we make a sequence of vectors containing all the components we need:

```
V[n] = (B[n], A[n], 1)
```

Then we can construct a matrix `M` so that:

```
V[i] = M*V[i-1]
```

And so:

```
V[n] = (M^(n-1))V[1]
```

Since the size of the matrix is fixed at 3x3, you can use [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) on the matrix itself to calculate `M^(n-1)` in *O(log n)* time, and the final multiplication takes constant time.

Here's an implementation in python with numpy (so I don't have to include matrix multiply code):

```
import numpy as np

def getSum(a,n):
    # A[n] = a + a^2 + a^3...a^n
    # B[n] = a + 2a^2 + 3a^3 +. .. na^n
    # V[n] = [B[n],A[n],1]

    M = np.matrix([
        [a, a, a],  # B[i] = B[i-1]*a + A[i-1]*a + a
        [0, a, a],  # A[i] = A[i-1]*a + a
        [0, 0, 1]
        ])

    # calculate MsupN = M^(n-1)
    n-=1
    MsupN=np.matrix([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]);

    while(n>0):
        if n%2 > 0:
            MsupN *= M
            n-=1
        M*=M
        n=n/2

    # calculate V[n] = MsupN*V
    Vn = MsupN*np.matrix([a,a,1]).T;
    return Vn.item(0,0);
```

Comment: Hi Matt, I think you lost me on the last line. I can get the correct answer using the other method, but I'm going wrong somewhere with yours. My `M` is a 3x3 upper triangular matrix of `a`'s, and my `V[1] = (a,a,1)`. Where did I mess up?

Comment: @beaker close, but the M(3,3) == 1.  I added an implementation.

Comment: Ah! That fixed it. Thanks :)

Comment: `*` and `*=` operations are element-wise multiplication. I think `@` should be used instead.

Comment: @GZ0 If you use the actual matrix type from np.matrix, then you get matrix multiplication for those.  I did test this.

Comment: @Matt I didn't realize that. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 4):

I assume `a, n` are nonnegative integers. The explicit formula for `a > 1` is

```
a * (n * a^{n + 1} - (n + 1) * a^n + 1) / (a - 1)^2
```

It can be evaluated efficiently in `O(log(n))` using
[square and multiply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) for `a^n`.

To derive the formula, you could use the following ingredients:

1. [explicit formula for geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)
2. You have to notice that this polynomial looks almost like a derivative of a geometric series
3. [Gaussian sum formula](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gau%C3%9Fsche_Summenformel) for the special case `a = 1`.

Now you can simply calculate:

```
sum_{i = 1}^n i * a^i                                    // [0] ugly sum
= a * sum_{i = 1}^n i * a^{i-1}                          // [1] linearity
= a * d/da (sum_{i = 1}^n a^i)                           // [2] antiderivative
= a * d/da (sum_{i = 0}^n a^i - 1)                       // [3] + 1 - 1
= a * d/da ((a^{n + 1} - 1) / (a - 1) - 1)               // [4] geom. series
= a * ((n + 1)*a^n / (a - 1) - (a^{n+1} - 1)/(a - 1)^2)  // [5] derivative
= a * (n * a^{n + 1} - (n + 1)a^n + 1) / (a - 1)^2       // [6] explicit formula
```

This is just a simple arithmetic expression with `a^n`, which can be evaluated in `O(log(n))` time using square-and-multiply.

This doesn't work for `a = 0` or `a = 1`, so you have to treat those cases specially: for `a = 0` you just return `0` immediately, for `a = 1`, you return `n * (n + 1) / 2`.

[Scala](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/) snippet to test the formula:

```
def fast(a: Int, n: Int): Int = {
  def pow(a: Int, n: Int): Int =
    if (n == 0) 1 
    else if (n == 1) a 
    else {
      val r = pow(a, n / 2)
      if (n % 2 == 0) r * r else r * r * a
    }

  if (a == 0) 0
  else if (a == 1) n * (n + 1) / 2
  else {
    val aPowN = pow(a, n)
    val d = a - 1
    a * (n * aPowN * a - (n + 1) * aPowN + 1) / (d * d)
  }
}
```

Slower, but simpler version, for comparison:

```
def slow(a: Int, n: Int): Int = {
  def slowPow(a: Int, n: Int): Int = if (n == 0) 1 else slowPow(a, n - 1) * a
  (1 to n).map(i => i * slowPow(a, i)).sum
}
```

Comparison:

```
for (a <- 0 to 5; n <- 0 to 5) {
  println(s"${slow(a, n)} <-> ${fast(a, n)}")
}
```

Output:

```
0 <-> 0
0 <-> 0
0 <-> 0
0 <-> 0
0 <-> 0
0 <-> 0
0 <-> 0
1 <-> 1
3 <-> 3
6 <-> 6
10 <-> 10
15 <-> 15
0 <-> 0
2 <-> 2
10 <-> 10
34 <-> 34
98 <-> 98
258 <-> 258
0 <-> 0
3 <-> 3
21 <-> 21
102 <-> 102
426 <-> 426
1641 <-> 1641
0 <-> 0
4 <-> 4
36 <-> 36
228 <-> 228
1252 <-> 1252
6372 <-> 6372
0 <-> 0
5 <-> 5
55 <-> 55
430 <-> 430
2930 <-> 2930
18555 <-> 18555
```

So, yes, the O(log(n)) formula gives the same numbers as the O(n^2) formula.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the formula for `a > 1`. I understand exponentiation by squaring now, but I'm not sure how to get the above formula. I can't use a geometric series sum formula directly because the ratio is different for each element.

Comment: Oh, is the formula gotten by manipulating the equation? I multiplied both sides by `(1 - a)` to get the formula you gave. Is that the correct way though? I feel like it's rather coincidence-ish that I can get the formula by multiplying both sides with `(1-a)` and simplifying the equation from there. I mean, how do I know that other problems might need to be multiplied by other things and not `(1-a)`?

Comment: @Richard The formula is obtained by plain calculation. You start with the original sum on the left, then you perform steps [1]-[5], and finally you obtain a simple arithmetic expression that gives exactly the same numbers as the original sum formula. I didn't use `(1-a)` anywhere, it seems to be just some factor that shows up in the denominator after applying the geometric series formula. If you don't understand some of the steps, you'd have to specify which ones ([1]-[5]). Sorry, StackOverflow does not support LaTeX formulas, so it's typographically suboptimal.

Comment: I don't understand the part where you transition from step [3] to step [4]. Formula of geometric series: `a * (r^n - 1) / (r-1)`, right? So in the series above, we have `a^0 i.e. 1 + a^1 + a^2 + a^3 + ... + a^n - 1`, and crossing out the `1`s, we have `a^1 + a^2 + ... + a^n`. Therefore, `a i.e. first element` is `a` and ratio is also `a`. We should have the formula `a * (a^n - 1) / (a-1)`? Yours is different than mine, I got confused there.

Comment: I got your formula using a different method: one that includes multiplication of `(1-a)`. I have finished the exercise and posted my code here: https://gist.github.com/TakeNoteIAmHere/d015d9fb40f53e7340a8ed89260196db. The formula derivation is on line 23-29.

Comment: @Richard I think you're confusing the `a` from your formula with the `a` from wikipedia's formula: your `a` here is their `r` there. The geometric series formula is `sum_{i = 0}^n a^i = (a^{n + 1} - 1) / (a - 1)`, that's what I use between steps [3] and [4]. Note that the formula starts at `i = 0`, so we needed `a^0 = 1` somewhere. Fortunately, we can simply add this constant out of nowhere, because under differentiation `d/da`, the constants simply don't matter. I tried to express it by adding `+1`, then immediately subtracting `-1`, and then differentiating the constant away.

Comment: I see! Okay, I get it now. I think that you should've still included the `-1` part for step[4] and make it disappear after derivation on step[5] on your before-edited answer. That confused me. Anyway, I get the concept, thanks! What about my way of formulating the equation, is it reliable (i.e. is it a good way to form equation like these)?

Comment: @Richard I reverted to the `+ 1 - 1` with subsequent elimination of `-1` by `d/da`. It's mostly matter of taste - it's all equal anyway.

Answer (score 2):

`a^n` **can** be indeed computed in `O(log n)`.

The method is called [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) and the main idea is that if you know `a^n` you also know `a^(2*n)` which is just `a^n * a^n`.

So if you want to compute `a^n` (if n is even) you can just compute `a^(n/2)` and multiply the result with itself: `a^n = a^(n/2) * a^(n/2)`.  So instead of having a loop up to `n`, now you only have a loop up to `n/2`. But `n/2` is just another number, and can be computed the same way, thus doing only half the operations. Halving the number of operations each time leads to the logarithmic complexity.

As mentioned by @Sopel in the comment, [the series can be written as a simple equation/function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20j*a%5Ej,%20j%3D1%20to%20n):

```
         a * (n * a^(n+1) - (n+1) * a^n + 1)
f(a,n) = ------------------------------------
                   (a- 1) ^ 2
```

So to find the answer you only have to compute the above formula, using the fast exponentiation described above to do it in `O(logN)` complexity.

Comment: I assumed that once you know this you can apply it to simplified form of the above series. Could the downvoter explain the reason for downvoting, did I say something incorrect?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked

Comment: @MattTimmermans How it does not? The sum formula is a math question which is offtopic for this site. The bigger issue, and actual question in my eyes, was that OP thought  `a^n` can only be computed in linear time. I don't think answers are supposed to write the entire implementation of a question, but just give pointers on where to look/go next so the OP can better understand the solution: "*Even if it is possible, I assume that it will involve the use of exponent n, which will introduce a n-time loop; thus causing the solution to not be O(log n).* "

Comment: And the formula was also linked in the WolframAlpha comment.

Comment: Your answer only provides one of at least 2 essential insights necessary to solve this problem.   How you can apply exponentiation by squaring to generate the required sequence is not at all obvious -- especially not obvious to someone who doesn't know how to do exponentiation by squaring.  You answered a question that you knew how to answer, but it was not the question that was asked.